# "在市中心的这家意大利饭馆很好。" or " 这家在市中心的意大利饭馆很好。" Regarding word order and grammar, are both these sentences correct?

Tags: grammar, word-order

"在市中心的这家意大利饭馆很好。" or " 这家在市中心的意大利饭馆很好。" Regarding word order and grammar, are both these sentences correct?

The first sentence comes from some learning material, so I assume it's correct. But after I realized what it was saying, I thought to myself, couldn't I say that like this "这家在市中心的意大利饭馆很好." Am I wrong? And if so, why?

Comment: Both are fine. The first one is more likely to be said considering the location of the speaker.

Comment: Both sentences work. Others talked about emphasis. For me, if you READ the plain text, there is no emphasis difference. The emphasis depends on where the accent is when you speak is out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though it seems both are acceptable in terms of the meaning conveyed, I do feel that splitting up the object in your suggestion, "这家意大利饭馆", (the whole phrase is the object and not just 意大利饭馆 alone), into two parts is bad syntax.

Also, in terms of vocalization, the second sentence is less "smooth" as it needs an enforced pause for the parenthesis, 在市中心的, before the sentence continues on.

Answer (score 2):

Both are correct and almost express the same meaning.

The slight difference is that the former puts emphasis on the location while the latter directly focuses on the restaurant mentioned.

The first sentence might somehow imply that you are talking about what restaurant is good in this area. The second one simply suggests a restaurant which is good and located in the downtown area.